# iPhone 5 screen in landscape proportion when system says it is not landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an app that needs to change it's dimensions when it is changed from landscape to portrait or vice-versa.  I have registered a notification like so:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "rotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil);
```

And I get the notification but there is one scenario where it fails.  When I pick the phone up, switch it to landscape, then set it down flat on the table without tilting it, I get a notification that it has changed out of landscape but I get dimensions that are still the old dimensions.  This is how I am checking:

```
let isLandscape = UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(currentDevice.orientation);
```

Here is a log:

Start in portrait:

```
Landscape: false
Bounds (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)
```

Turn phone on it's side:

```
Landscape: true
Bounds (0.0, 0.0, 568.0, 320.0)
```

Lay flat on table:

```
Landscape: false
Bounds (0.0, 0.0, 568.0, 320.0)
```

I am brand new to this so perhaps I am using the wrong API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake.  I assumed there were only two orientations, but I looked at the UIDeviceOrientation enumeration and there are several:

```
case Portrait // Device oriented vertically, home button on the bottom
case PortraitUpsideDown // Device oriented vertically, home button on the top
case LandscapeLeft // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the right
case LandscapeRight // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the left
case FaceUp // Device oriented flat, face up
case FaceDown // Device oriented flat, face down
```

So my assumption that "not landscape means portrait" was not correct.